# How to select last 6 months from news table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the last 6 months of entries in a table, I have a column called datetime and this is in a datetime mysql format.

I have seen many ways using interval and other methods - which method should I use? Thanks

Comment: if the field is really called datetime you'll need to use ` to surround it.  datetime is a reserved word.  Pablo's response would work xcept where he has `your_dt_field` you may need to put `datetime` with the proper escape ` character.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
 .... where yourdate_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: DATE_SUB() function subtracts the interval from the given date. In this case "now() - 6 months".

Comment: Inside `DATE_SUB()` function, Can i also use `MAX(<date_column>)` instead of `now()`??? Because i'm facing a similar situation and i have to check the last 6 months data from the last date present in the date column instead of today's date.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
select *
  from table 
 where your_dt_field >= date_sub(now(), interval 6 month);
```

Query reads: give me all entries in `table` where the field corresponding to the entry date is newer than 6 months.

Comment: your_dt_field what will be it's format ? also how can use there systems current date

Answer (score 7):

You can get last six month's data by subtracting `interval of 6 month` from `CURDATE()` (**`CURDATE()` is MySQL function which returns Today's date**).

```
SELECT * FROM table 
         WHERE your_date_field >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH;
```

Or you can use `BETWEEN` operator of MySQL as Below:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
         WHERE your_date_field BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND CURDATE();
```

Answer (score 3):

MYSQL query to find rows from last 6 months

```
SELECT *

FROM tableName
 
WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), dateColumn) <= 180;
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried @user319198 answer to display last 6 months (sum of) sales, it worked but I faced one issue in the oldest month, i do not get the sales amount of the whole month. The result starts from the equivalent current day of that month.

Just I want to share my solution if any one interested:-

```
yourdate_column > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 MONTH)
limit 6
```

Also it will be great if anyone has better solution for my case J.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use TIMESTAMPDIFF

```
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, your_date_column, now()) <= 6 )
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, this looks like a solution as I'm using it with MariaDB, take a look at WHERE clause:

```
SELECT MONTH(yourTimestampOrDateColumn) AS MONTH, USER, ActionID, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_ACTIONS, ROUND(SUM(totalpoints)) AS TOTAL_PTS
FROM MyTable
WHERE MONTH(yourTimestampOrDateColumn) BETWEEN MONTH(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY MONTH;
```

[image: queryResults]

On the image we see only months where user had actual data recorded in a DB (thus showing only 4 months instead of 6).

So this month is 10th (October), 6 months ago was 4th month (April), thus query will look for that interval (from 4 to 10).