# Get the values for last 6 months in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to get last six month values from the database.  **Here is my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8029/8)**.  I need to get the values dynamically.  Now February.  So I need August to January values from database. If March then the values should automatically change to October to February. So the thing I need to get last six month values.

My Code follows.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ratepersqft` (
  `price_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `project_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `date` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `rate_per_sqft` double default NULL,
  `common_location` varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`price_id`)
); 

INSERT INTO `ratepersqft` (`price_id`, `project_id`, `date`, `rate_per_sqft`, `common_location`) VALUES
    (1, 1, '2012-07-01 ', 2800, 'ECR'),
    (2, 2, '2012-07-02 ', 1550, 'ECR'),
    (3, 3, '2012-07-03 ', 1850, 'ECR'),
    (4, 4, '2012-07-04 ', 4425, 'ECR'),
    (5, 5, '2012-07-05 ', 2300, 'ECR'),
    (6, 1, '2012-08-01 ', 2900, 'ECR'),
    (7, 2, '2012-08-02 ', 1650, 'ECR'),
    (8, 3, '2012-08-03 ', 1950, 'ECR'),
    (9, 4, '2012-08-04 ', 4525, 'ECR'),
    (10, 5, '2012-08-05 ', 2200, 'ECR'),
    (11, 1, '2012-09-01 ', 3000, 'ECR'),
    (12, 2, '2012-09-02 ', 1450, 'ECR'),
    (13, 3, '2012-09-03 ', 2050, 'ECR'),
    (14, 4, '2012-09-04 ', 4625, 'ECR'),
    (15, 5, '2012-09-05 ', 2100, 'ECR'),
    (16, 1, '2012-10-01 ', 3100, 'ECR'),
    (17, 2, '2012-10-02 ', 2150, 'ECR'),
    (18, 3, '2012-10-03 ', 1850, 'ECR'),
    (19, 4, '2012-10-04 ', 4725, 'ECR'),
    (20, 5, '2012-10-05 ', 1900, 'ECR'),
    (21, 1, '2012-11-01 ', 3200, 'ECR'),
    (22, 2, '2012-11-02 ', 2250, 'ECR'),
    (23, 3, '2012-11-03 ', 1850, 'ECR'),
    (24, 4, '2012-11-04 ', 4825, 'ECR'),
    (25, 5, '2012-11-05 ', 2300, 'ECR'),
    (26, 1, '2012-12-01 ', 3300, 'ECR'),
    (27, 2, '2012-12-02 ', 2350, 'ECR'),
    (28, 3, '2012-12-03 ', 1850, 'ECR'),
    (29, 4, '2012-12-04 ', 4925, 'ECR'),
    (30, 5, '2012-12-05 ', 2400, 'ECR'),
    (31, 1, '2013-01-01 ', 3400, 'ECR'),
    (32, 2, '2013-01-02 ', 2000, 'ECR'),
    (33, 3, '2013-01-03 ', 2450, 'ECR'),
    (34, 4, '2013-01-04 ', 5025, 'ECR'),
    (35, 5, '2013-01-05 ', 2500, 'ECR'),
    (36, 1, '2013-02-01 ', 3500, 'ECR'),
    (37, 2, '2013-02-02 ', 2100, 'ECR'),
    (38, 3, '2013-02-03 ', 2550, 'ECR'),
    (39, 4, '2013-02-04 ', 5125, 'ECR'),
    (40, 5, '2013-02-05 ', 2600, 'ECR'),
    (41, 1, '2012-06-01 ', 1800, 'ECR'),
    (42, 2, '2012-06-02 ', 1150, 'ECR'),
    (43, 3, '2012-06-03 ', 1350, 'ECR'),
    (44, 4, '2012-06-04 ', 3425, 'ECR'),
    (45, 5, '2012-06-05 ', 2100, 'ECR');
```

I am trying this query and it give me all the values in the Database.

```
SELECT *
  FROM ratepersqft
 WHERE MONTH(date) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: You have tagged as mySQL and SQL server...which one exactly? :-)

Comment: This is mysql.  You can refer the fiddle

Comment: ah, you did not specify that records from the future should be excluded. I am changing my answer to add this requirement

Comment: Kindly refer the second line.  Now Feb.  I need to get the values from Aug to Jan.  Its clear right?

Comment: For the future, you should state all your requirements clearly - you will get answer much faster. Otherwise other people have to practice in mind reading :-)

Comment: Okay i will correct myself.  Sorry for the inconvenience happens to you.

Comment: the where clause should be like `BETWEEN startdate AND enddate`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select last 6 months from news table using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941377/how-to-select-last-6-months-from-news-table-using-mysql)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For MYSQL: you may use  `date_add`:

```
 SELECT * FROM ratepersqft 
WHERE date < Now() and date > DATE_ADD(Now(), INTERVAL- 6 MONTH);
```

For SQL Server:, [`dateadd`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) :

```
  SELECT * FROM ratepersqft 
 WHERE date < Now() and date > DATEADD(Month, -6, Now());
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8029/48

**Please wrap your date column name with backticks given it is a reserved key word. **

MYSQL update:

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8029/67)

```
SELECT *
FROM ratepersqft 
WHERE date_format(date,'%Y-%m') < 
                     date_format(now(),'%Y-%m')
and date_format(date,'%Y-%m') >= 
                     date_format(now() - interval 6 month,'%Y-%m')
order by date desc;
```

Comment: Now() doesn't exist in SQL Server. For SQL Server use getdate() [http://forums.asp.net/t/1431963.aspx?+NOW+is+not+a+recognized+built+in+function+name+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1431963.aspx?+NOW+is+not+a+recognized+built+in+function+name+)

Comment: use `DATE_SUB` insted

Answer (score 4):

This will consider all dates to be rounded to the beginning of the month for comparisons, and will get last 6 months from today's date:

```
SELECT *
FROM ratepersqft
WHERE date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
  AND date <  DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01')
```

Obligatory [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9d720/28).

Comment: It is getting 7 months value.

Comment: earliest value it gives is `2012-08-02`. as far as I can tell, it was 6 months ago. you may want to use `>=` instead of `>` if exact day matters. Or you must get values starting on the 1st of the month?

Comment: you should clearly say your requirements: does it mean that you require that all dates are rounded to the month for comparisons?

Comment: Yes Obviously.  It should be.  I need the past 6 month values.

Answer (score 1):

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f8029/44/0)

If you want full months only

```
SELECT *
FROM ratepersqft
WHERE date between date_format(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH), '%Y-%m-01')
           and  date_sub(date_format(CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-01'), interval 1 day);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is very useful for when your data is in MM-YYYY format and then you want to fetch data  between six month. Enjoy.

```
SELECT * FROM demo WHERE attendance_year_month < SUBSTRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,11) and attendance_year_month
>=DATE_SUB(SUBSTRING(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,1,11), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Output:
[here i am teching my six month previous data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr4fN.png)

Answer (score -1):

```
 SELECT
YEAR(DATE) AS YEAR,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 1) AS JAN ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 2) AS FEB ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 3) AS MAR ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 4) AS APR,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 5) AS MAY ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 6) AS JUNE ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 7) AS JULY ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 8) AS AUG,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 9) AS SEP ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 10) AS OCTOBER ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 11) AS NOV ,
SUM(MONTH(DATE) = 12) AS DECE
FROM ratepersqft
WHERE  DATE >= NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH 
GROUP BY 1;
```