# PHP Synchronization of old Data

Tags: php

I have already applied synchronization on my application by transferring the data from offline server to online server and vice versa. The problem i am heading up with is that i want to set a duration for that data i.e. it should sync data of past 6 months. Is something like this is possible. The data from the tables should came despite of there is not such Date Field in all the tables. I am working in PHP and mySQL. All the help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you using date fields in the data?

Comment: can you post one of the queries used to get the data

Comment: $qry = "SELECT 
     `Id`, 
     `PayScale`, 
     `ParentPayScaleId`, 
     `Description` 
    FROM 
    `tbl_lookup_payscale_type`";
    
  $qryRes = mysql_query($qry, $this->offlineDBConn);
  if ( $qryRes )
  {
   $rows = array();    
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryRes))
   {
    array_push($rows, $row);
   }
   
   $this->freeResult();
   return $rows;
  }

Comment: using the column having `date` or `timestamp` datatype and referring to the following link, you should get a head start on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643454/get-the-values-for-last-6-months-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I will surely try this :-)

Comment: Thanks alot Sir.. I got my work done :)