# MySQL get sum of amount for last 6 months

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query to get the total `amount` for every month in the last 6 months.
The idea is something like:

```
Select 
 sum(amount) as Total, data
From 
 myTable
Where
 date /* How can I filer by month? */
Group By
 /* Group by each month */
```

Sample data

```sql
create table mytable ( Order_date date, Amount float);

insert into mytable values('2021-02-13',24.15);  
insert into mytable values('2021-02-13',12.00  );
insert into mytable values('2021-02-16',14.12  );
insert into mytable values('2021-03-02',17.01  );
insert into mytable values('2021-03-14',18.25  );
insert into mytable values('2021-4-1',19.24  );
```

Amount is decimal and date is date time field.

Desired output:

| Total | month |
| --- | --- |
| 50.269999504089355 | 2021 February |
| 17.010000228881836 | 2021 March |

Is it possible to create this with only one query?

Comment: please show us your schema for `myTable`. We don't know what your columns are, so filtering the date could be done a dozen different ways.

Comment: To filter out last 6 month : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643454/get-the-values-for-last-6-months-in-mysql/14643487
Group by month : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508791/mysql-query-group-by-day-month-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Try this query:

```
Select 
    sum(amount) as Total,  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
From 
    myTable
Where
    date>= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01')  - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
Group By
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date)
```

But only month can be duplicate if you consider date range for more than year. january 2020 and january 2021 will be same in above query. So you should group by on month and year as below:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
create table mytable ( Order_date date, Amount float);

insert into mytable values('2021-02-13',24.15);  
insert into mytable values('2021-02-13',12.00  );
insert into mytable values('2021-02-16',14.12  );
insert into mytable values('2021-03-02',17.01  );
insert into mytable values('2021-03-14',18.25  );
insert into mytable values('2020-12-1',19.24  );
```

---

**Query #1**

```
Select 
    sum(amount) as Total, 
    concat(year(order_date), ' ' , monthname(Order_date)) month
From 
    mytable
Where
    Order_date between CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH and curdate()
Group By
    concat(year(order_date), ' ' ,monthname( Order_date) );
```

Output:

| Total | month |
| --- | --- |
| 19.239999771118164 | 2020 December |
| 50.269999504089355 | 2021 February |
| 35.260000228881836 | 2021 March |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure why the post was closed. I think I cleared explained wha ti needed. The filter for last 6 months is not working. For example, insert in the table some data for September 2020 or after March 202. These data should not show in the query, but it does

Comment: You explained clearly. Let me check the condition.

Comment: i have just checked second query and it’s not adding any value from march 2020.

Comment: but It's not workinf for future date. changed the answer

Comment: it will now ignore future dates.

Comment: You might edit the question with sample input output to reopen the question if you want.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a champ

Comment: You are most welcome. Best wishes.

Comment: Just one minor details in my case, I wanted the last 6 months including the current month, so I change the where condition to ```INTERVAL 5 MONTH```. My bad, I should have explained it

Comment: Another detail, the filter is not actually getting the first day of the 6 months ago. It's filtering by ```curdate()```, so it is considering the current day, not the first day of the month.

Comment: I have changed my answer